# Using reinterpret_cast with bool

Tags: c++, boolean

C++ automatically sets `bool` values to either `true` or `false`, even if the type actually holds a 1 byte value.

So `bool(123) == true` is true, with

```
int i = 123;
bool b = i;
int j = b;
```

`j` takes the value `1`.

---

But does this remain the case when `reinterpret_cast` is used with `bool*` pointers? E.g.

```
static_assert(sizeof(bool) == 1, "assuming sizeof(bool) is one in this example...");
std::uint8_t i = 123;
bool* b = reinterpret_cast<bool*>(&i);

int j = *b; // j becomes 1
if(*b == true) ... // condition is true
```

Are these results guaranteed to be true, or is it undefined behavior. (i.e. can be compiled rely on the assumption that `bool` objects are already internally represented as `1` and `0`).

Comment: _"Are these results guaranteed to be true, or is it undefined behavior."_ Well, using `reinterpret_cast` is rather _unspecified behavior_.

Comment: Where do you get that the size of bool must be 1?

Comment: @NathanOliver Isn't that the smallest size that could be picked for a data type?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is but `sizeof(bool)` is implementation defined.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The smallest, but not the largest. There are implementations where `bool` is larger.

Comment: Well, I see the argument. At least the same applies to the `reinterpret_cast` in general.

Comment: Since `&i` doesn't actually point to a `bool` object, the result is undefined.

Comment: You are breaking strict aliasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [basic.lval]:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined:
>   (10.1) — the dynamic type of the object,
>   (10.2) — a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (10.3) — a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (10.4) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
>   (10.5) — a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>   of the object,
>   (10.6) — an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or nonstatic
>   data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or
>   contained union),
>   (10.7) — a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
>   (10.8) — a `char` or `unsigned char` type.

You're attempting to access the stored value of a `uint8_t` through a glvalue of type `bool`. That fits none of those 8 categories, hence the behavior is undefined.

Comment: But since `uint8_t` is an implementation defined typedef, and that type is most likely `unsigned char`, wouldn't that make the result implementation-conditionally well defined, per 10.8?

Comment: @rodrigo It doesn't matter – accessing a `bool` through an `unsigned char*` is well defined, but the reverse isn't.